# Calculating the probability to hit a number after already reaching a previous number

Tags: probability

Let's say there is an infinite scale from $1$-infinity. We are starting from one and increasing by tenths.

> - The chance of getting to any given number is $1$/( that number ) $=$ ( reciprocal ). So for example, the chance of getting to $1.5$ is $1/1.5 = 66.67\ \%$, the chance of getting to $2$ is $1/2 = 50\ \%$, and so on.
> - If we've already made it to a certain point ( arbitrarily picking $1.5$ as an example ), what is the probability of making it to any other given point ( let's say $2.5$ ) ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like an exercise in conditional probability. Recall that
$$
\mathbb{P}[A|B] = \frac{\mathbb{P}[A \cap B]}{\mathbb{P}[B]}.
$$
Let $B$ be the event of reaching past the first point and $A$ be the event of reaching past the second point. Can you finish this?

Comment: This is a new concept to me but doing a quick google search, I've found plenty of reference material. So if I'm reading this right:

Probabillity of (A) * Probability of (B) / Probability of B =

.4*0.6666666667 / 0.6666666667 =

0.4000000002

I believe ∩ is the intersection so we will be multiplying

Comment: @WilsonTan correct